# Image with hyperlink in Radeditor

Tags: radeditor

when I am using `LinkManager` on an inserted image, a blue border starts coming around the images. Can some body help me to remove this border?

Answer (score 1):

This is a default behavior of IE inside the editable iframe elements, which can be customized via the following CSS rule:

```
a img
{
    border: none;
}
```

Put the class in a CSS file and load it through the CssFiles property of RadEditor. It will clear all borders shown for images inside an  tag.

Best regards,
Rumen Jekov

Comment: We use a modified version of RadEditor in another product so not sure if paths are the same, but adding the above in `<style></style>` tags to the 'Default.aspx' file works for us